# MySQL - Number format - Separated with Comma

Tags: mysql, date-format, number-formatting, number-table

I have a query of MySQL like this-

```
SELECT avg('total_cost') FROM 'employee'
```

And then I am getting output like this-

```
1254589687.26587952
```

But I like to have a output like this-

```
1,25,45,89,687.26
```

So, a comma separator should be added and number should be rounded.

Is there any way in MySQL?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The manual is your friend: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
+----------------------------------+
| format(123456789.26, 2, 'ta_in') |
+----------------------------------+
| 12,34,56,789.26                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/locale-support.html -- locales